# Split a string in actionscript?

Tags: string, actionscript, actionscript-2

How do I accomplish this in actionscript (example in c#):

```
string[] arr = { "1.a", "2.b", "3.d", "4.d", "5.d" };
int countD = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
{
    if (arr[i].Contains("d")) countD++;
}
```

I need to count a character in an array of strings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are four ways to do it... (well, 3.something)

```
var myString:String = "The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy "
           + "dog. The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.";
var numOfD:int = 0;

// 1# with an array.filter
numOfD = myString.split("").filter(
            function(s:String, i:int, a:Array):Boolean {
                return s.toLowerCase() == "d"
            }
        ).length;

trace("1# counts ", numOfD); // output 1# counts 4


// 2# with regex match
numOfD = myString.match(/d/gmi).length;
trace("2# counts ", numOfD); // output 2# counts 4

// 3# with for loop
numOfD = 0;
for (var i:int = 0; i < myString.length; )
    numOfD += (myString.charAt(++i).toLocaleLowerCase() == "d");
trace("3# counts ", numOfD); // output 3# counts 4

// 4# with a new prototype function (and regex)
String['prototype'].countOf = 
    function(char:String):int { 
        return this.match(new RegExp(char, "gmi")).length;
    };
// -- compiler 'strict mode' = true
numOfD = myString['countOf']("d");
trace("4# counts ", numOfD); // output 4# counts 4
// -- compiler 'strict mode' = false
numOfD = myString.countOf("d");
trace("4# counts ", numOfD); // output 4# counts 4
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
for(var i:int = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
{
    if(arr[i].indexOf("d") != -1)
        countD++;
}
```

Use indexOf rather than contains. It will return -1 if the character is not in the string, otherwise the string contains at least one instance.

Comment: thanks for the point, although I actually need to do this in actionscript2 (flash8)

Comment: According to Adobe, indexOf was supported as far back as Flash 5: http://www.adobe.com/support/flash/action_scripts/actionscript_dictionary/actionscript_dictionary692.html

Comment: you need to mention the actionscript 2 requirement in your question

Answer (score 0):

Use the `match` function on a javascript string.
http://www.cev.washington.edu/lc/CLWEBCLB/jst/js_string.html

Sorry, works the same.

Comment: I need to do this in actionscript2 (flash8)

Comment: JavaScript and ActionScript are both EcmaScript and the string object works the same on both.

Answer (score 0):

Found it:

```
var searchString:String = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.";
var index:Number;

index = searchString.indexOf("L");
trace(index); // output: 0

index = searchString.indexOf("l");
trace(index); // output: 14

index = searchString.indexOf("i");
trace(index); // output: 6

index = searchString.indexOf("ipsum");
trace(index); // output: 6

index = searchString.indexOf("i", 7);
trace(index); // output: 19

index = searchString.indexOf("z");
trace(index); // output: -1
```